# render PHP content within section

Tags: php

I need to render some PHP content, within php tags to display HTML loaded from a database. This is what I have:

```
<?php
$this->section['left-column'] = '<?php echo $page->left; ?>';
?>
```

But this of course does not work...

I assumed this would work:

```
<?php
$this->section['left-column'] = ' . echo $page->left; . ';
?>
```

But it didn't :(

Can anyone advise the correct way to enter this?

Thanks.

Comment: What? Is `$this->section['left-column'] = $page->left;` what you want?

Comment: When you are inside PHP tags (`<?php ... ?>`) you can run PHP directly. That's what PHP tags are for.

Comment: The `' . echo $page->left; . '` is just a string, try `<?php echo $page->left; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
$this->section['left-column'] =  $page->left;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP string won't execute unless it is evaluated.

```
<?php
$this->section['left-column'] = eval('echo $page->left;');
?>
```